# Iteration over lines of a file fail

Tags: python, file, iteration

I've wrote this script to find all the lines that are not followed by this: (currentLine + " downloaded")

```
with open('filename') as f:
    for line in f:
        if not line.strip('\n') + " downloaded\n" in f:
            print line
```

It just print the first match and ends the iteration.
For example, for this file:

```
WhatsApp
Windows Live Mail
Windows Live Mail downloaded
XChat
XChat downloaded
Zimbra TGZ to PST Converter
Zimbra TGZ to PST Converter downloaded
ZOOK DBX to EML Converter
ZOOK DBX to EML Converter downloaded
ZOOK DBX to EMLX Converter
ZOOK DBX to EMLX Converter downloaded
ZOOK DBX to MBOX Converter
ZOOK DBX to MBOX Converter downloaded
ZOOK DBX to MSG Converter
```

I expect it to print `WhatsApp` and `ZOOK DBX to MSG Converter`. But it just print first match which is `WhatsApp`.

Comment: `if not line.strip('\n') + " downloaded\n" in f:` is silently iterating on `f` so it consumes the list at the first pass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if not line.strip('\n') + " downloaded\n" in f:` is silently iterating on `f` so it consumes the list at the first pass.

You'd have to create a `list` with `f = list(f)` so the exhaustion effect is removed, but that's not performant (`O(n)` lookup)

I would create 2 `set()` objects, one for items, the other one for "downloaded" items:

```
downloaded = set()
products = set()

with open('filename') as f:    
    for line in f:
        if line.endswith("downloaded\n"):
            # store the info minus the "downloaded" prefix
            downloaded.add(line.replace(" downloaded\n",""))
        else:
            products.add(line.rstrip())

print(products - downloaded)
```

in the end, just print the product minus the downloaded products. prints:

```
{'ZOOK DBX to MSG Converter', 'WhatsApp'}
```

This solution works even if the lines aren't properly ordered.

Comment: Knowing about that reason of consumption was more important for me than having a working script. Thanks for both :)

Comment: To print each element on a separate line I changed last line to this:
result = products - downloaded
for elem in result:
    print elem